# SQL Server: Group By All Columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 16 columns and more than a million records (about 200k will be added on a monthly basis, all at once, in bulk).

Something like this:

```
+----+------+------+-----+--------+----------------+
| Id | Col2 | Col3 | ... | Col 15 | Numeric Column |
+----+------+------+-----+--------+----------------+
|  1 | xxx  | xxx  | ... | xxx    |             10 |
|  2 | yyy  | yyy  | ... | yyy    |             20 |
|  3 | zzz  | zzz  | ... | zzz    |             30 |
|  4 | xxx  | xxx  | ... | xxx    |             40 |
+----+------+------+-----+--------+----------------+
```

Most of the records are unique, but there are duplicates.
I need to create a view on this table that aggregates these duplicate lines, considering every single column.
When records are aggregated, I need to show the SUM of the last Numeric Column.
As an example, my view needs to aggregate record 1 and 4.
The expected result is (note the SUM of 50 (10+40)):

```
+------+------+-----+--------+-----------------------+------------------------------+
| Col2 | Col3 | ... | Col 15 | Sum Of Numeric Column | Amount Of Aggregated Records |
+------+------+-----+--------+-----------------------+------------------------------+
| xxx  | xxx  | ... | xxx    |                    50 |                            2 |
| yyy  | yyy  | ... | yyy    |                    20 |                            1 |
| zzz  | zzz  | ... | zzz    |                    30 |                            1 |
+------+------+-----+--------+-----------------------+------------------------------+
```

I have accomplished this with the following query:

```
SELECT
    [Column 2],
    [Column 3],
    ...,
    [Column 15],
    SUM([Numeric Column]) AS [Sum Of Numeric Column],
    COUNT(*) AS [Amount Of Aggregated Records]
FROM dbo.MyLargeTable WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Column 2],
    [Column 3],
    ...,
    [Column 15]
```

This view will server as a base view for other views, that require the data to be aggregated. This means that it needs to be quite fast. My question is simple: knowing that this view needs to serve data to other views, is this the way to go? Is there a way to optimize this query? Can I arrange something with indexing?

Thank you.

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: There's no real problem so far. I'm just asking for advise on the way I use GROUP BY here to aggregate duplicate lines. The query is already quite slow and looking at the future addition of millions of rows, I want to have the best possible solution.

Comment: Then visit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me your query is already optimized and does not require any further optimization. Using CTE will only degrade performance in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but the idea is that you create 2 CTE's and only calculate the aggregates when they are needed. You could test this and compare it to your own query.

```
WITH Dups AS 
(
SELECT
    [Column 2],
    [Column 3],
    ...,
    [Column 15],
    SUM([Numeric Column]) AS [Sum Of Numeric Column],
    COUNT(*) AS [Amount Of Aggregated Records]
FROM dbo.MyLargeTable WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Column 2],
    [Column 3],
    ...,
    [Column 15]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
),

REGS AS 
(
SELECT
    [Column 2],
    [Column 3],
    ...,
    [Column 15],
    [Numeric Column],
    1 AS [Amount Of Aggregated Records]
FROM dbo.MyLargeTable WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Column 2],
    [Column 3],
    ...,
    [Column 15]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)

SELECT * FROM Regs UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Dups ORDER BY SomeCol
```